# How to add a key value in couchbase where the value is derived from an already existing key value in the document

Tags: sql, json, database, couchbase, sql++

I have a json document in couchbase whose structure looks like this

```
"root": {
          "type": "TEST",
          "parameters": {
            "numbers": [
              "1",
              "2-001",
              "3",
              "2-001",
              "5-002"
           ] 
          }
        }
```

I need to add a new key value pair and make the document look like this

```
"root": {
          "type": "TEST",
          "parameters": {
            "numbers": [
              "1",
              "2-001",
              "3",
              "2-001",
              "5-002"
           ],
          "unique": [
              "1",
              "2",  
              "3",
              "5"
          ] 
         }
        }
```

I should strip off whatever is after -, and select the unique elements present inside of it.

Comment: Do you want to do this with N1QL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this with N1QL, you can use an [`ARRAY`](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/collectionops.html#array) transformation combined with [`ARRAY_DISTINCT`](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/arrayfun.html#fn-array-distinct). The transformation will be up to you. You could use one of the [REGEXP_ functions](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/patternmatchingfun.html) or something simple like a [`SPLIT`](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/stringfun.html#fn-str-split). For example:

```
select ARRAY_DISTINCT(ARRAY SPLIT(v,"-")[0] FOR v IN d.root.parameters.numbers END) as `unique`, d.root.parameters.numbers
from mybucket d;
```

That will return document(s) in the form:

```
[
  {
    "numbers": [
      "1",
      "2-001",
      "3",
      "2-001",
      "5-002"
    ],
    "unique": [
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      "5"
    ]
  }
]
```

If you want to actually make changes to the document(s), you can make that `SELECT` into an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE mybucket
SET root.`unique` = ARRAY_DISTINCT(ARRAY SPLIT(v,"-")[0] FOR v IN root.parameters.numbers END)
where root.`unique` is missing;
```

Comment: TIL N1QL is pronounced "nickel"